# Eonasdan datetimepicker doesn't work in inline mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have an issue: when I use datetimepicker in inline mode, console shows me this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateFormat' of null

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true
  });
});
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maxdonetsk/jahsjkkn/

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to add an input box to the div, as dtp will not work without it. I am updating your fiddle

Comment: updated your fiddle . You need to add an input type="text" to the div , else you will keep getting null

Answer (score 2):

Just change your datetimepicker js to

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
```

and your code will work

here is the fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/w0nk1c5z/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot some HTML :-)

This is what I have changed:

```
           <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
```

to

```
           <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker12'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/273tzgnz/1/

To clarify: this has nothing to do with inline-mode. This has to do with the fact that you didn't have an input for the datetimepicker to bind to.